# Why am I getting a syntax error in setting this Array into a class?

Tags: php

I am getting a syntax error but I don;t understand exactly why, here is my code:

```
class VerifyEmail {

     private $ip_pool = array("167.114.48.81","167.114.48.82"....);
     private $ip_to_use = $this->ip_pool[array_rand($this->ip_pool)]; //ERROR HERE
     .....
```

I tried also:

```
     private $ip_to_use = $ip_pool[array_rand($ip_pool)];
```

with no luck.

Am I missing something? Or you cannot do an array rand of a private variable when setting up the variables?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `array_rand` has 2 parameter, [Have a look in here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: @LongKim second parameter is optional, that's not it.

Comment: Try this private $ip_to_use = $this->ip_pool[array_rand($this->ip_pool, 1)];

Comment: What is your PHP version? using `$this` when defining default values feels wrong. this logic might be more suitable in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the following notice in my IDE for that line

> expression is not allowed as a field default value

I can only suggest moving your rand call into the `__construct()` method

```
class VerifyEmail {

  private $ip_pool = array( "167.114.48.81", "167.114.48.82");
  private $ip_to_use;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->ip_to_use = $this->ip_pool[ array_rand( $this->ip_pool ) ];
  }

}

var_dump( new VerifyEmail() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently trying to access the array as an index of the array itself.

Considering you're just trying to assign one string from within the `$ip_pool` array to `$ip_to_use`, all you need is `$ip_to_use = array_rand($this->ip_pool)`.

```
class VerifyEmail {  
  private $ip_pool = array("167.114.48.81","167.114.48.82"....);
  private $ip_to_use = array_rand($this->ip_pool);
  ...
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: then use it as $ip_to_use[0] to get the first element? BTW, private $ip_to_use = array_rand($this->ip_pool); is also marking a syntax error.

Comment: You can use it with just `$ip_to_use`. `array_rand()` without a second parameter only returns **one** random element from the array. You can specify how many elements to return with an optional secondary `int`  parameter (so `array_rand($this->ip_pool, 2)` would return two random IP addresses) :)

Comment: `private $ip_to_use = array_rand($this->ip_pool);` is also showing a syntax error.